# I was modeling something, and when I tried to undo, it made the "skin", as you could call it disappear, and I can't see what I've already drawn

Tags: texturing

Initially when i tried to undo, the answer google brought up was outdated, and I pressed ctrl+alt+z, then I did a little more digging, and pressed ctrl+z, that STILL didn't revert to any earlier edits, so I went to the edits menu, and looked through my edit history, when I pressed edit, something happened and my model looked something like this:[image]

Answer (score 1):

To view all the undoable steps, go to *Edit* > *Undo History* and you can select which step you want to revert to. Blender keeps track of a ton of actions such as selecting / unselecting objects, so that's most likely whats going on.

[image]

You can also increase/decrease the number of undo steps that Blender remembers in the *User Preferences.*

[image]

Comment: Appreciated, but do you have any idea how to get the texture back on my model? The net isn't very useful, because there's no reference.

Comment: Do you mean how the 3D Viewport is displaying your model as a wireframe? You can press Shift+Z to toggle wireframe view mode or hold Z to bring up a pie menu to select the viewport shading mode. You can also change the shading mode with the 4 buttons with circles on them in the top right of the 3D Viewport